# Is there anyway to make web app's components do not look so small on mobile

Tags: frontend

I've made a website. It looks nice when using PC, but not good when using smartphone (Too small). Is there anyway to fix that?
Here is my website: https://hai-weather-forecast.herokuapp.com/

[image: PC version]

[image: Mobile version (iphone X)]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add the responsive meta tag in the head element?

```html
<head>
   ...
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   ...
</head>
```

Here is the background [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

I tested by open the url you provided, setting the same device size with developer tools, and adding that meta tag in the head element editing the html by hand.

Beffore adding meta tag

[image]

After adding meta tag
[image]

Cheers!

Comment: No problem. Note that this is just the tip of the iceberg, I think you should get into responsive design if you need full control of your layout across different devices and screen sizes.